# Android have <fragment> ingore padding - Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an xml file like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/callText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-16dp"/>
```

How can I have the view fill the whole width?

Thanks

Comment: Remove all the `android:paddingXYZ` attributes from the parent. Also remove all the `android:layout_marginXYZ` from the FrameLayout. Oh, well, you can leave the Top and Bottom ones, since you asked for width only.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I want to keep the parent padding, but just ignore it for this one view?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein isn't that what I did in the `<fragment>` with `android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"`

Comment: You need to set `clipToPadding="false"` in the relative layout.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it.